# How to reference a file from root folder to any django app folder

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here i'm create to create an entry which takes a HTML file input. Now I'm trying to do with the following code but getting permission denied. How can I reference that HTML template in my testcase.

```
 # CREATE EMAIL TEMPLATE
        data = {
            "user":user,
            "platform_subscriber":project,
            "name": "TESTCASE TEMPLATE",
            "html_template": "../nice.html"
        }
        email_template, created = EmailTemplate.objects.custom_get_or_create(data)
        print("The key",email_template)
        self.email_template  = email_template.id
```

**log :**

```
aise SuspiciousOperation("Attempted access to '%s' denied." % name)
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to '../nice.html' denied.
```

Answer (score 0):

Django can't access files that are stored above the working directory... otherwise your webapp could read things it shouldn't, which is a security risk.

Usually we would keep the template in the `templates` directory of your app.

So move `../nice.html` to `./templates/nice.html` and you should be fine.

There are many more sophisticated options to manage templates if you check [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loader.get_template).